# Как удалить все символы в строке после первого пробела?

Tags: c++

Имеется строка, в которой есть в начале номер:

```
string name = "01 I'm a Slave 4 U.mp3";
```

Как сделать так, чтобы остался только номер?

```
"01"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, найти первый пробел

```
auto pos = name.find(' ');
```

и, если он есть, удалить все, начиная с него

```
if (pos != string::npos) name.erase(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для изменяемой строки в стиле Си

```
char s[] = "01 I'm a Slave 4 U.mp3";
char *p = strchr(s, ' ');
if(p) {
  *p = '\0';
  // использование s ...
}
```

Для неизменяемой строки в стиле Си

```
const char *s = "01 I'm a Slave 4 U.mp3";
const char *p = strchr(s, ' ');
if (p) {
  char *d = malloc(p - s + 1);
  memcpy(d, s, p - s);
  d[p - s] = '\0';
  // использование d ...
  free(d);
}
```

Впрочем, код можно сделать менее развесистым, не потеряв в безопасности, если использовать расширения glibc (нужно определить макрос `_GNU_SOURCE`). Для первого случая

```
const char *s = "01 I'm a Slave 4 U.mp3";
*strchrnul(s, ' ') = '\0';
// использование s ...
```

А для второго вот так

```
const char *s = "01 I'm a Slave 4 U.mp3";
char *d = strndup(s, strchrnul(s, ' ') - s);
// использование d ...
free(d);
```

Comment: Но вопрос-то по c++!

Comment: но это код должен работать и в плюсах, но метки я всё равно дополнил

Comment: Асмовые вставки тоже в плюсах работают, может тогда добавить ответ на асме и влепить соответствующую метку? Я не считаю это правильным подходом. Не надо раздувать вопрос.

Comment: к сожалению, в C++ ассемблерные вставки не стандартизированы, в отличие от функций из заголовков `<сstdlib>` или `<cstring>`

Comment: [Последний абзац](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5110/176217).

Answer (score 0):

`name.erase(std::find(begin(name), end(name), ' '), end(name));`

Answer (score -2):

```
for(i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
  if(name[i] == ' '){
    name.resize(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы какой-то мрак написали. Зачем так мудрить?

Comment: Resize string
Resizes the string to a length of n characters.
If n is smaller than the current string length, the current value is shortened to its first n character, removing the characters beyond the nth.

Может я что-то неправильно понимаю?